# jest.doMock not calling mock function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is my component to be tested.
// WelcomePgaeContainer.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import WelcomePage from "./WelcomePage";
import api from "../../../api";
import apiUrl from "../../../apiUrls";
import { Loader } from "../../../shared/components";



const WelComePageContainer = () => {
const [welcomeData, updateWelcomeData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    api.get(apiUrl.WELCOME_PAGE.GET_WELCOME_DATA).then(({ data }) => {
    updateWelcomeData(data);
   });
  }, []);

 return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(welcomeData).length ? (
       <WelcomePage />
     ) : (
       <div data-testid="welcome-page-loader" className={styles.loaderContainer}>
      <Loader size={5} />
    </div>
  )}
  </div>
 );
};

export default WelComePageContainer;
```

// api.js

```
 import axios from "axios";

 const api = axios.create();

 api.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

 api.interceptors.request.use(
   config => {
   config.withCredentials = false;
   return config;
 },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
 );

api.interceptors.response.use(
 response => response,
 error => { 
  return Promise.reject(error.response);
 }
);

export default API;
```

// Welcome.test.js

```
   it("test welcome page is loaded and async data call is made once", async () => {
       jest.doMock("../../src/api", () => {
        const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        mock.onGet(apiUrl.WELCOME_PAGE.GET_WELCOME_DATA).reply(200, WELCOME_DATA);
    });
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    const { findByTestId } = render(
        <Router history={history}>
        <WelComePageContainer />
        </Router>
    );
    const welcomeViewElement = await findByTestId("welcome-data-container");
    expect(welcomeViewElement).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I am trying to mock import api from "../../../api"; of WelcomePgaeContainer.jsx in my test file. However, when calling from Welcome.test.js the actual is getting invoked rather than the mocked one.